# Support for dynamic installer parameters?

Tags: install4j

We are evaluating install4j as a replacement for JWrapper and have come across one necessary feature that we are not sure how to implement. Our application is 3-tier with a Java client application, and we are using JWrapper for client install/update with its 'dynamic parameterisation' feature to inject params into the installer media file at download time. The best example of these parameters would be the hostname of the application server the installer was downloaded from, since we do not have a single fixed server that we can hard-code.

We need the downloaded installer to require no interaction from the user, as they cannot be expected to know the values for these parameters.

So I guess the short form of my question would be: Is there any way we can get parameters known only on the server (after the installer media has been built) into the installer when it is launched on the client?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally not possible because it will break the signature of the media file. The only way is to pass the information as an argument or in a file next to the media file.